Kendo ui angular grid scroll issue when popup is opened
setHoveredCell(item: any, swConfig: any, event: any,popupgrid: TemplateRef<{ [Key: string]: unknown }>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(this.transposed ? (swConfig.hwConfig == item.hwConfig) : (swConfig.testCase == item.testCase)) {
        if((!item.hasOwnProperty('hovered') || item.hovered == false)) {
            Object.defineProperty(swConfig, 'hovered', {
                value: true,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }

    if(event.target.classList.contains('active-cell')) {
        if(this.popupRef) {
            this.popupRef.close();
            this.popupRef = null;
            const cellRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            const offsetX = cellRect.left;
            const offsetY = cellRect.bottom + window.scrollY;
            this.popupRef = this.popupService.open({
                content: popupgrid,
                offset: { top: offsetY, left: offsetX },
            });
        } 
        else {
            const cellRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            const offsetX = cellRect.left;
            const offsetY = cellRect.bottom + window.scrollY;
            this.popupRef = this.popupService.open({
                content: popupgrid,
                offset: { top: offsetY, left: offsetX },
            });
        }

        // this.gridPopUpShow = true;
        // this.hoveredElement = swConfig;
        swConfig.hovered == true ? this.calculateFirstColumnWidth('grid1') : '';
    }
}

When the last element in the grid is hovered to show the popup. the grid gets scrolled to the left automatically.
I tried adding prevent.default() method but still it's not working.
